# Cannot see browser windows started by service

Tags: selenium, browser, service, windows-7

I have a Windows 7 service which starts up browsers (selenium), If I run the service with the Local System account when a browser starts, a little box pops up saying "A program running on this computer is trying to display a message", and if I click view the message I can see the browser windows and watch my test run.

However I need to run the service as my user account as the browsers that get spawned need some permissions that Local Service doesn't have.  But when I set the service to run as my user account I don't get the pop up so I cannot see the browsers, and the browser also isn't visible if I log on as the account that is running the service.

Does anyone have any advice as to how I might be able to get these browser windows visible?

Thanks for any help offered 
Adam

Comment: What browser are you trying to launch?

Comment: Any :) my tests run on IE8, FF25 and Chrome30, all of which are not visible when run from the service.
If I run selenium from the command line rather than from the service, the browsers are visible.
Thanks for you comment!

Comment: I should point out here that the IE driver in particular uses some Windows API calls that are expressly not supported to work in a Windows service application. The implication of this is that the IE driver is not supported running in a Windows service application. If you're trying to use WebDriver from a Windows service, You're Doing It Wrong.

Comment: @JimEvans That's interesting to know!!
I am using RC rather than WebDriver, but I assume that the same applies.
Unfortunately it is an inherited setup and the wider test management system requires selenium running as a service as it probes the service to ensure availability. So I guess until I have time to do a big rework I am stuck.
Thanks for your help

Comment: You know Selenium RC is deprecated, and being moved toward its end-of-life, right? This had been the project's policy for 2+ years now. If you're not already starting to migrate your tests to WebDriver, you're far, far behind the curve.

Comment: @JimEvans Yep, I am sadly aware, however I have just joined a company which is on RC and has best part of 1000 tests over 20 servers all in a proprietary test management system so it is a big move which will take time. Therefore I still to make small improvements to the RC setup at the moment.
Thanks again for you help and information